# PHP json_decode my file but always returning NULL

Tags: php, json

I try to json_decode this file: http://iklankita.info/form_5.txt
but always returning NULL. I try to validate in jsonlint.com. It is valid already.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NztzI.png

Actually it is a 'form' format generated by FormCrafts.

Here's code I used:

```
$data = file_get_contents('form_5.txt');
$json = json_decode($data);
var_dump($json);
```

It is returns NULL. In fact, I try another same format, and works: http://ncrafts.net/formcraft/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/contact_us.txt

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the code you've written.

Comment: Copy/paste your file here and see if it looks correct: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/.  JsonEditorOnline correctly interprets it - but the "build" variable looks funky.  ALSO: Update your post with the PHP code that's reading the file.

Comment: *"I try to validate in jsonlint.org. It is valid already."* - You said it validated it? It said *JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data*

Comment: Can you post what you have tried programmatically?

Comment: yes Fred, please check my screenshot.

Comment: Iff it is valid, then you can replace the `file_get_contents()` with the actual content and get the same results. Note that you will probably have to escape a few things in the content and that afterwards you should edit the JSON until only the relevant parts remain. That said, what about the error info that the JSON lib gave you?